# Let $I$ be an interval bounded above and bounded below. Then, $I=[a,b], [a,b), (a,b]$, or $(a,b)$ for some real numbers $a$ and $b$.

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

I have to show which of the possible four intervals $I$ is, to do so, I know I must find the endpoints and decide if $I$ is open, half-opened, or closes. I was told to assume $a, b$ are the infimum and supremum respectively, but I cannot figure out how to find the endpoints.

Can anyone assist me, please?

Comment: Each one of those intervals is bounded below and bounded above if $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Darsen, yeah the hypothesis assumes it is bounded above and below.

Comment: How do you define an interval?